# OS X mouse pointer speed varies with different mouse

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse

OS X Snow Leopard

It seems that when using different mice on OS X may have different pointer speed and scrolling speed. For example, when using my Logitech basic laser mouse, the pointer speed is like normal. But when using MX Performance or Anywhere, it's very slow, I will have to adjust the pointer speed in mouse configuration to max. Even with max, it's still a bit slow.

Basically, just feel the plug and play on OS X is terrible. I need re-adapt to it every single time. This is not the case on Windows OS.

Also, the mouse scrolling speed varies with different mouse too. But usually they are all very slow, usually scroll 1 line at a time. If I adjust it in mouse configuration, it turns to scroll too much lines.

I have Logitech official mouse driver (LCC) installed. But either tuning in LCC or mouse configuration doesn't make things better.

Has anyone have similar issue? How to resolve it? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more of a Logitech software problem:
[Linky](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050629045425132)

MouseZoom might help you adjust the speed better but you will still have to open a preference pane to adjust things whenever you plug in a different mouse. [Mousezoom](http://benh57.com/mousezoom.html)